# @dynamic how to set properties?

Tags: core-data, dynamic

**H file:**

```
@interface TaskTypeEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *color;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *task;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *taskCount;
@end
```

M file:

```
@implementation TaskTypeEntity

@dynamic color;
@dynamic image;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic status;
@dynamic task;
@dynamic taskCount;



- (void) add:(TaskTypeEntity*)data
{
    TaskTypeEntity *taskTypeEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_NAME inManagedObjectContext:content];
    taskTypeEntity.name = data.name;
    taskTypeEntity.image = data.image;
    taskTypeEntity.color = data.color;
    BOOL result = [content save:nil];
    if (result) {
        NSLog(@"success%@", data);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"fail");
    }
}

 @end
```

When setting the property， It doesn't work:

```
TaskTypeEntity *taskTypeEntity = [TaskTypeEntity alloc];
taskTypeEntity.name = @"dfdfd";
[taskTypeModel add:taskTypeEntity];
```

error：
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TaskTypeEntity setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a7b070'

Please help me, thank you

Comment: It's not the way to create entities (though it's not the way to create any Objective-C object). Read Apple's core data guide please.

Comment: [Introduction to Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: Thank you, my English is not very good, but I will read it carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `NSManagedObject` class reference:

> Important:  This method is the designated initializer for
>   NSManagedObject. You must not initialize a managed object simply by
>   sending it init.

The method of reference in the above quoted text is `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` and can be used thusly:

```
NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" 
             inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

**EDIT**  (In response...)

This code is just plain wrong:

```
TaskTypeEntity *taskTypeEntity = [TaskTypeEntity alloc];
```

Even if `TaskTypeEntity` were not a `NSManagedObject` it would still be wrong, as you never called an initializer.

The fact that it is a `NSManagedObject` makes it even more wrong, because you are never supposed to alloc/init one of those.

Why not try something like this (I assume you are using transformable attributes for image and color):

```
+ (instancetype)taskTypeEntityInMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
                               name:(NSString*)name
                              image:(UIImage*)image
                              color:(UIColor*)color
{
    TaskTypeEntity *taskTypeEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_NAME inManagedObjectContext:content];
    taskTypeEntity.name = name;
    taskTypeEntity.image = image;
    taskTypeEntity.color = color;
    return taskTypeEntity;
}
```

Then you can call it...

```
TaskTypeEntity *taskTypeEntity =
    [TaskTypeEntity taskTypeEntityInMOC:context
                                   name:(NSString*)name
                                  image:(UIImage*)image
                                  color:(UIColor*)color];
```

Comment: I know that, but I just want to be wrapped into a function, and convenient to call.Like this:

Comment: - (void) add:(TaskTypeEntity*)data
{
    TaskTypeEntity *taskTypeEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_NAME inManagedObjectContext:content];
    taskTypeEntity.name = data.name;
    taskTypeEntity.image = data.image;
    taskTypeEntity.color = data.color;
    //taskType.status = data.status;
    if (taskTypeEntity != nil) {
        BOOL result = [content save:nil];
        if (result) {
            NSLog(@"success%@", data);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"fail");
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"fail");
    }
}

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: Only in this way, if there is no better way。谢谢！！Thank you.